# Unexpected Token ')' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been struggling to get this if statement too work for too many hours now. It tells me that ')' on the 9th line is a token error. Any recommended fixes would be great! I copied it directly from the video I am watching and it still isn't working.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connect = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'db'
});

connection.connect(function (error) {
  // callback
  if (!!error) {
    console.log('Error');
  } else {
    console.log('Connected');
  }
});

app.get('/', function (req, resp) {
  connection.query("Select * from db", function (error, rows, field) {
    if (!!error) {
      console.log('Error');
    } else {
      console.log('Succesful');
    }
  });
})

app.listen(3306);
console.log('Running on Port 3000')
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: The code around this might be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Here is the rest of the code. Nice to know that its just happening to me!

Comment: Still cannot reproduce the error with your code edited code. Just incorrect `!!` logic in your `if(!!error)` statement. Should just be one !. And `var connect` should be `var connection`. Fixing those syntax errors outputs `Running on port 3000` just fine and `Successful` when hitting localhost.

Comment: @cb64 If there's only one `!` it will have the opposite logic.

Comment: Is it still complaining about line 9 of this code?

Comment: There are no errors. And yes `!` will have the opposite logic, but there is no reason to use that logic. Correct me if Im wrong but `if(!!error){}` is the same as `if(error){}` so the `!` operators are essentially canceling each other out.

Answer (score 0):

Your `var connect = mysql.createConnection({…` is wrong because the variable that you are using in your code is `connection` – not `connect`.

Also notice that the double `!!` to check the *error* in the `if` are nonsense.

Must be:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'db'
});

connection.connect(function (error) {
    // callback
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error');
    } else {
        console.log('Connected');
    }
});

app.get('/', function (req, resp) {
    connection.query("Select * from db", function (error, rows, field) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error');
        } else {
            console.log('Successful');
        }
    });
})

app.listen(3306);
console.log('Running on Port 3000')
```